# Formula completion

Tags: regression, descriptive-statistics

I have, for `v` and `x` this values:

```
V    X

1.02 1788
1.10 2120
1.11 2232
1.30 2400
1.31 2494
1.32 2587
1.50 3014
1.51 3229
1.54 3563
1.60 3940
1.70 4540
1.80 5354
1.81 5746
1.83 5986
1.90 6591
1.92 7272
1.93 7444
1.94 7510
2.00 8237
2.01 8426
2.10 9181
2.16 10444
2.17 11729
2.20 12342
2.30 13778
2.35 15106
2.36 16093
2.40 17023
2.41 17362
2.42 18467
2.43 19024
2.50 23368
2.52 24267
2.53 25075
2.60 28392
2.70 30429
2.76 31347
2.80 32582
3.00 34641
3.01 35108
3.10 37233
3.15 38031
3.21 41486
3.30 42164
3.40 44261
3.41 45039
3.42 45831
3.50 46135
3.55 47516
3.56 48165
3.60 48686
3.61 49561
3.65 49764
3.66 50527
3.70 51968
3.72 52565
3.73 52870
3.74 53196
4.00 53642
4.10 54953
4.11 55054
4.20 57923
4.21 58071
```

I'm trying to recreate this formula (to know X using V) but the nearest i got was something like this:

X = V / V / ( ( V + 2.5 ) ^ 6 );

Can anyone try to understand this?

Comment: Did you try linear regression?

Comment: Yes, i think, but i didn't found the right formula.

Comment: You are looking for an exact formula?

Comment: If possible, the closest that i arrived was the one i put on question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an example: Fit with a polynomial of degree 3

[image: Fit with a polynomial of degree 3]

Comment: $44468 - 72911 v + 36356  v^2 - 4363 v^3$

Comment: Witch program did you used to draw this?

Comment: Mathematica. I use the command NonlinearFit to find the curve. With a polynomial of degree 6 we get $-289659 + 833633v - 931260 v^2 + 518158 v^3 - 151355 v^4 + 22418  v^5 - 1333 v^6$ which gives a better aproximation.